# Using a Postgres window statement in the FROM of a sub query

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I have the following SUB QUERY as part of a SELECT statement. Which is supposed to take one calculated time, away from another calculated time.

However Postgres doesn't like having the Window function within the FROM clause.

```
(SELECT count(*) AS work_hours
FROM   generate_series (TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + MAX(wog.endtime) OVER(PARTITION     BY woas.workorderid ORDER BY wog.endtime DESC)/1000 * INTERVAL '1 second'
                  , TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + nth_value(wog.endtime,2) OVER(PARTITION BY woas.workorderid ORDER BY wog.endtime DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)/1000 * INTERVAL '1 second' - interval '1h'
                  , interval '1h') h
WHERE  EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM h) < 6
AND    h::time >= '08:00'
AND    h::time <= '18:00') AS "Max minus Second Max",
```

Postgres returns the following error:

```
ERROR: cannot use window function in function expression in FROM
```

How can I reformat the above statement, so that it parses without error?

Update:

I dont think the structure of the query is the issue. If I put timestamp string in place of the functions it works fine.

```
 (SELECT count(*) AS work_hours
 FROM generate_series (timestamp '2018-01-06 13:30'
                  , timestamp '2018-01-08 21:29' - interval '1h'
                  , interval '1h') h
 WHERE  EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM h) < 6
 AND    h::time >= '08:00'
 AND    h::time <= '18:00') "Time Difference" from workorder wo
```

Comment: How does the function look? What does it return?

Comment: It returns a timestamp in the following format '2018-01-11 14:27:07'

Comment: A single timestamp? Or multiple ones.

Comment: Each "TIMESTAMP 'epoch' ..." line returns a single timestamp value

Answer (score 0):

After "FROM" clause a table/view to query the data from is expected.

You refactor the query like this:

```
select count(*) from (
    select generate_series( ....)
    where (cond1 and cond2..)
```

Obviously it will not work when you put the function in the "from" clause.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue, please see my update. With string values the query works fine. So that tells me the overall structure is ok

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have a solution, you might want to try this.  I think it does what you want.

Set-up test: similar enough to your situation, I hope.

```
create table work_order_times
(
    work_order_id  integer,
    end_time       bigint     -- milliseconds
);

insert into work_order_times (work_order_id, end_time) values (23, extract(epoch from now()) * 1000);
insert into work_order_times (work_order_id, end_time) values (23, (extract(epoch from now()) - 20000) * 1000);
insert into work_order_times (work_order_id, end_time) values (57, (extract(epoch from now()) - 40000) * 1000);
insert into work_order_times (work_order_id, end_time) values (57, (extract(epoch from now()) - 60000) * 1000);
insert into work_order_times (work_order_id, end_time) values (57, (extract(epoch from now()) - 80000) * 1000);
```

Check set-up:

```
select
    work_order_id,
    end_time, 
    to_timestamp(end_time / 1000) as end_timestamp
from
    work_order_times
order by
    work_order_id,
    end_time;

 work_order_id |   end_time    |     end_timestamp      
---------------+---------------+------------------------
            23 | 1516251234772 | 2018-01-18 04:53:54+00
            23 | 1516271234769 | 2018-01-18 10:27:14+00
            57 | 1516191234774 | 2018-01-17 12:13:54+00
            57 | 1516211234773 | 2018-01-17 17:47:14+00
            57 | 1516231234772 | 2018-01-17 23:20:34+00
(5 rows)
```

The Query:

```
select
    work_order_id,
    generate_series (penultimate_timestamp, latest_timestamp, interval '1 hour')
from
    (
        select
            work_order_id,
            to_timestamp(latest_end_time / 1000) as latest_timestamp,
            to_timestamp(penultimate_end_time / 1000) as penultimate_timestamp
        from
            (
                select
                    work_order_id,
                    row_number()  over last_2_timestamps as row_number,
                    max(end_time)  over last_2_timestamps as latest_end_time,
                    lead(end_time) over last_2_timestamps as penultimate_end_time
                from
                    work_order_times
                window
                    last_2_timestamps as (partition by work_order_id order by end_time desc)
            ) x
        where
            row_number = 1
    ) y;
```

The results:

```
 work_order_id |    generate_series     
---------------+------------------------
            23 | 2018-01-18 04:53:54+00
            23 | 2018-01-18 05:53:54+00
            23 | 2018-01-18 06:53:54+00
            23 | 2018-01-18 07:53:54+00
            23 | 2018-01-18 08:53:54+00
            23 | 2018-01-18 09:53:54+00
            57 | 2018-01-17 17:47:14+00
            57 | 2018-01-17 18:47:14+00
            57 | 2018-01-17 19:47:14+00
            57 | 2018-01-17 20:47:14+00
            57 | 2018-01-17 21:47:14+00
            57 | 2018-01-17 22:47:14+00
(12 rows)
```

The PostgreSQL documentation does mention some restrictions about how window functions can be nested, but it seems to work like this.

It would make things slightly simpler to store the endtime as a timestamp rather than a number of milliseconds, which is what it appears to be, but maybe you don't have the opportunity to do that.